# NodeJS - Using sequelize, unable to create tables in different schemas with same name

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create junction tables for many to many relationship negotiation, I have 3 schemas shared, shop1 and shop2

the shared schema has a users table and a roles table, each of the shop schemas need to have a UserRoles table to negotiate the many to many relationship (many users can have many roles)

It's showing as having synced the database, and getting no errors, however it will only create 1 of the UserRoles tables, if I comment out the model for the one that does get created, it will create the other, is there a way for different schemas to have the same table name?

Shared.Users model:

```
// models/database/Shared/users.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../../configuration/database');

const SharedUser = sequelize.define('Users', {
  ID: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },  
  Firstname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Lastname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Payroll: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
  },
  AppNumber: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
  },
  Active: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  LastUpdatedBy: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
  },
  LastUpdatedOn: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
}, 
{  
    schema: 'Shared'
  });
console.log('SharedUser model loaded successfully.');
module.exports = SharedUser;
```

Shared.Roles model:

```
// models/database/Shared/Roles.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../../configuration/database');

const SharedRole = sequelize.define('Roles', {
    ID: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  Name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Description: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(250),
  },
  Permissions: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(250),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  Active: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false,
  },
}, 
{  
    schema: 'Shared'
  });
console.log('SharedRole model loaded successfully.');
module.exports = SharedRole;
```

Shop1.UserRoles

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../../configuration/database');
const { Users, Roles } = sequelize.models;

const Shop1UserRoles = sequelize.define('UserRoles', {
  UserId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  RoleId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
},
  {
    schema: 'Shop1'
  });

// Define foreign key relationships with aliases and targetKeys
Shop1UserRoles.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'UserId', targetKey: 'ID', as: 'User' });
Shop1UserRoles.belongsTo(Roles, { foreignKey: 'RoleId', targetKey: 'ID', as: 'Role' });

console.log('Shop1UserRoles model loaded successfully.');
module.exports = Shop1UserRoles;
```

I have also tried to setup different database connections for each schema but the nit seems to not be able to reference the shared schema from the shop schemas

I'm using mssql as the dialect

Am I doing this correctly? or is there a better way to do it?